# clicking on radio button label not selecting the button itself

Tags: html

I have a simple radio buttons. It kinda of works. The problem is when I click on Yes, the radio button is selected. When I click on No, it is not selected.

**I want it to have same id !**

Below is my code...

JSFIDDLE: 
http://jsfiddle.net/bwYrA/

SOURCE CODE:

```
 <div class="control-group oneLine">
   <label class="control-label" for="custom1" >1. Did you telephone the store prior to visiting?</label>
   <div class="controls">
     <div class="row">
       <label class="radio col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 ol-lg-6" for="custom1">
         <input name="custom1" id="custom1" value="1" type="radio">
         Yes </label>
       <label class="radio col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 ol-lg-6" for="custom1">
         <input name="custom1" id="custom1" value="2" type="radio">
         No </label>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Don't use the same ID. If you want them to share some properties, use the same class.

Answer (score 8):

Change the inputs to the following. Your ids are overlapping, you have to make them unique while keeping the input name the same.

```
      <label class="radio col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 ol-lg-6" for="custom1">
        <input name="custom" id="custom1" value="1" type="radio">
        Yes </label>
      <label class="radio col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 ol-lg-6" for="custom2">
    <input name="custom" id="custom2" value="2" type="radio">
    No </label>
```

No, you can't do it with the same ID.

You can likely do it with javascript, but I'm not sure. If you can include jquery, put this in a script tag and you should be set. It'll change the name and for attributes once the page loads.

```
$('[value="2"]').attr("name","custom2")
$('[value="2"]').parent().attr('for','custom2')
```

Comment: Yes that would solve the problem. However I can not change the id to custom2 as you noted. The values are going to the backend and I need them to be of same id...Is it possible with same id? Thanks for your input. :) Appreciate it

Comment: @Himu Usually the data is bound to the `name` attribute, not the id.

Comment: @thgaskell yeah you are right, nice answer jboneca.